# GKE ReadOnlyMany - how to fill with content

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Hy,

How can i copy content on an readonlymany disk inside GKE?

Can i convert readwriteonce to readonlymany?

BR

Answer (score 0):

Before changing access mode from ROX to RWO,  make sure your volume is mounted to a single node (scale down to 1 replica).

Then just edit yaml of your PV object

```
kubectl edit pv <pv-name>
```

and set

```
accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
```

Or, if you are using dynamically provisioned PersistentVolumes, you have to edit pvc rather than pv